# Count rows returned from mysql query with distinct values

Tags: php, mysql

I am tryimg to count the number of rows returned from a mysql query using the code below. I cannot get the count despite trying many things. Could the problem be distinct vales. Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,'>',-2), count(*) as location FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `count()` as the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

May be the following queries would answer exactly what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '>', -2)) as location 
FROM table_name;
```

Or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT location) as total 
FROM table_name
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, '>', -2) != location;
```

Comment: Do you think this question might have been asked on Stackoverflow before?  Basic questions are almost always duplicates, please flag accordingly.

Comment: It has not been exactly answered. I think so. I didn't find myself any answer that can satisfy this one. I've your words in my head. So don't worry!